# Listitem's li.Value not rendering HTML instead displaying code

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using an admin dashboard on a WebForms ASP.NET C# application, the template caters for notifications which are displayed in a list `ul`. I've created the notification classes and am able to create and dismiss notifications however displaying them in the pretty format that the template offers is proving to be a headache - I've spent far too much time on such a simple task! The notification data is pulling correctly, I just need to sort out the display. I have to take into consideration that the inner HTML of the `li` has to store HTML that is dynamically generated based on notification type etc.

Here's the site.master asp code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <asp:BulletedList ID="notificationList" CssClass="dropdown-menu-list scroller" runat="server" style="height: 250px;" data-handle-color="#637283">
        </asp:BulletedList>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the c# code behind it:

```
string preTime = "< a href = \"javascript:;\" > < span class=\"time\">";
string preIcon = "</span>< span class=\"details\">";
string newOfferIcon = "<span class=\"label label-sm label-icon label-success\"><i class=\"fa fa-plus\"></i></ span > ";
string acceptOfferIcon = "<span class=\"label label-sm label-icon label-success\"><i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i></ span > ";
string declineOfferIcon = "<span class=\"label label-sm label-icon label-warning\"><i class=\"fa fa-times-circle\"></i></ span > ";
string postMessage = "</span></ a >";
foreach (var message in notices)
    {
        ListItem li = new ListItem();
        TimeSpan difference = currentTime - message.notificationDate;

        li.Value = preTime + time + preIcon + declineOfferIcon + message.notificationMessage + postMessage;
        notificationList.Items.Add(li); // add the new li element to the notifications list
    }
```

In order to match the template's structure, I am adding links and spans where necessary through concatenation. At the moment it is encoding the HTML in the strings and the output is pure HTML.

I am open to suggestions on restructuring as required, my only requirement is keeping the outputted `li` elements and HTML structure as below:

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:;">
        <span class="time">just now</span> <!-- time string -->
        <span class="details">
            <span class="label label-sm label-icon label-success"> <!-- this line changes programmatically -->
                <i class="fa fa-times-circle "></i>
            </span> 
            New user registered. <!-- message string -->
        </span> 
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Better would be to use repeater control and create item template in it and binding it to Notices list.

Comment: Thanks @ChetanRanpariya that solved it - don't know why I thought using the `BulletedList` and `ListItem` was better practise, this repeater method is far more flexible!